# Select array from nothing

Tags: mysql

I can do a single select by itself where there is no table:

```
select "hi" as "col";

+-----+
| col |
+-----+
| hi  |
+-----+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

What I would like to do is the same thing, but have two or more results, such as:

```
select ???;

+-----+
| col |
+-----+
| hi  |
+-----+
| lo  |
+-----+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Any ideas on how to select an array of things from nothing? Want to use this construct to do a mass insert without having to list every row by hand. Data isn't in the DB anywhere already.

Comment: You're going to have to list every row regardless. Why are you complaining about the notation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select 'hi' as col
union all
select 'lo'
```